# How to disable a button using bootstrap while using jquery window or viewport size?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am new with jQuery and was wondering how to disable bootstrap button using tablet and desktop viewport size.
I know how to disable the button but I only want to disable when the screen size are tablet and desktop.

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width()<768)
  {
    $('#sec-nav').click(function() {
      $("#sec-nav *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
    });
  }
});
```

or i tried this

```
     $(function(){
    setSizeAlerts();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        setSizeAlerts();
    });
   });



     function setSizeAlerts(){
      $('#sec-nav [data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }  


if ($(window).width() < 768) { 
    return false;

    }
     })
  };
```

but doesn't enables it when i say return false if its less then 768

HTML

```
            <div class="quickLinks col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                   <nav class="navbar secondary-nav" 
                    role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">


                <div class="nav navbar-nav" id="sec-nav">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle2 collapsed" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#secondary-nav" 
                  aria-expanded="false">

              <span class="Quicklinks"><p>Quick Links</p></span> <i 
                    class="fas fa-chevron-right quickChevron"></i>
            </button>
            </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="secondary-nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav boxin">
         <li role= "presentation" class="dropdown">
             <div class="dropdown">

            <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
                id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
                 haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> 
                HP ProDesk 400 G3
             <i class="fas fa-chevron-right chevright"></i>
            </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria- 
               labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#">System Drive replacement </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Content Drive replacement </a></li>
             </ul>
             </div>
          <li>
         <ul>
         </div
```

I figured it out!!!

```
    $(function(){
    setSizeAlerts();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        setSizeAlerts();
    });
    });



      function setSizeAlerts(){
      $('#sec-nav [data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
    if ($(window).width() > 768) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }  


     if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
    return false;

     }
        })
           };
```

is the arrows greater and less that were backwards

Comment: There is no language construct `If` in Javascript.

Comment: Try to implement with this I think this will help you little..
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to do prevent the toggle events using the following click event

```
$('#sec-nav [data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }    
});
```

to toggle the disabled state you use:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        $("#sec-nav *").prop("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $("#sec-nav *").prop("disabled", false); //re-enable the disabled button
      }
});
```

Comment: what exactly is not working, you need to use both snippets

Comment: its still toggling using both of the snipppets like mobile view doesnt toggle but i want it to and when i get to tablet it still toggles

Answer (score 1):

There are two different way to do that.
1) Using javascript to detect the browser

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 $('#sec-nav').click(function(){
         $("#sec-nav *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
        });
}
```

2) I found a function that detects the client screen size using `DisplayMetrics()`:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

float yInches= metrics.heightPixels/metrics.ydpi;
float xInches= metrics.widthPixels/metrics.xdpi;
double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(xInches*xInches + yInches*yInches);
if (diagonalInches>=6.5){
    // 6.5inch device or bigger
}else{
    // smaller device
}
```

Comment: foy your first solution where do i put the specific 768px. its works but when i go to tablet or any size button is disabled so i only need it to be certain sizes